# MSALErrorDomain error -42101 - MSALErrorMismatchedUser

Tags: ios, azure-ad-msal

One of our users on an iOS app is seeing the following error:

> MSALErrorDomain error -42101 - MSALErrorMismatchedUser

We are not currently able to reproduce the problem internally and have tried to understand what could cause this issue.

So far, what we know is that it seems this error is being raised by a call to `acquireTokenSilent`.

Our app only supports one account being signed in at any given time and logging out / deleting the app does not address the issue. The same user is able to use a different account authenticated via MSAL without issues.

We use MSAL in a pretty simple fashion where the user performs an interactive login through `acquireToken` first, and then any request for data made by the app uses `acquireTokenSilent` in order to obtain the `accessToken` that is then passed to the request made to the backend. When logging out, we remove all accounts from the `MSALPublicClientApplication`.

We do not use keychain sharing.

Any insight on what scenario could be causing this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lied in the fact that at some point during development, we changed the URL used to initialize the `MSALAuthority` object.

This change seems to prevent the proper removal of keychain data following the removal of a `MSALAccount` from the `MSALPublicClientApplication` instance.

Deleting all keychain data for our app using code found [here](https://bootstragram.com/blog/deleting-keychain-items/) resolved the issue.